# Constant speed along path

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, path

i want to move an object along a path and i want to create a "trail" behind this object. So i created a path (shift A > cuve > path), i moved the points, added some, created some loopings, etc...

Then i used a constraint on my object to make it follow the path. It worked perfectly.

In my curve settings > path animation > frames i have 150. I added some "extrusion" in curve settings > geometry, Bim, i have a curve mesh that i can render. I added a keyframe to the frame 1 in the  curve settings > geometry > bevel > end with the value of 0. At the frame 150 i did the same with a value of 1. But when i play the animation, the object move faster than the "trail", and at the end of the animation the "trail" and the object are finally at the same spot. I tryed to change the keyframe to have a linear interpolation for the bevel value, but the object still moving faster and slower depending of the distance between the anchors of the path curve.

Is that possible to make make this speed constant ? Considering the path as a line with a start and an end and not as a start, few checkpoints and and end.

thanks.

(english is not my native language, so i hope the question is clear)

Comment: did you try checking the keyframes you made in the graph editor ans setting the interpolation to linear?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's in the *Geometry > Bevel Settings > Use Spline* in the *Bevel > Bevel mapping > Start & End*.